# Using a loop for input vailidation and exception handling

Tags: java, loops, try-catch

How can I use a loop for input validation alongside try and catch blocks for catching an Input mismatch exception?

Here is my main method

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class labBookFortyThree {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner myInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        double circle, rect1, rect2, cyl1, cyl2;
        int input = 0;
        System.out.println("Press 1 to calc circle, 2 for rect, 3 for cyln");

        try {
            input = myInput.nextInt();
        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("Please enter a proper value");
        }

        if (input == 1) {
            System.out.println("enter radius");
            circle = myInput.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("area of circle is " + areas.area(circle));
        } else if (input == 2) {
            System.out.println("enter length and height");
            rect1 = myInput.nextDouble();
            rect2 = myInput.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("area of rect is " + areas.area(rect1, rect2));
        } else if (input == 3) {
            System.out.println("enter rad, height");
            cyl1 = myInput.nextDouble();
            cyl2 = myInput.nextDouble();
            int useless = 0;
            System.out.println("Area of cyl is " + areas.area(cyl1, cyl2, useless));
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my class area

```
public class areas {
    public static double area(double rad) {
        double area = 3.14 * (rad * rad);
        return area;
    }

    public static double area(double width, double height) {
        double area = width * height;
        return area;
    }

    public static double area(double rad, double height, int useless) {
        double area = (3.14 * (rad * rad) * height);
        return area;
    }
}
```

Where should i put a loop for input validation? Is there a better way? And what can i do creatively in the catch or try block?

Comment: First, you should indent your code! Also, wherever you are getting input.

Comment: Funny, just a couple of hours ago I read a question on Programmers about whether excessive whitespace can hurt code readability. There the OP said he was told off by colleagues because he sometimes inserted 3-4 lines of whitespace. The general consensus was that it's overboard and if there's a need in that much space to denote different blocks, they should be divided into different functions and/or classes and files. And now I see a piece of code with 7 (seven...) line breaks, in a window that fits on a phone screen.

Comment: Um, what's the loop for?

Comment: The loop is for getting a proper value for the user input from the Scanner method .nextInt()

Comment: Thank you Elliot Frisch, i never knew about those methods, it works now as i want it to work.

Comment: @Ro Siv, might be off topic, but you might also want to try giving the variable and methods in the Areas class meaningful names so it would be more understandable. Like getArea for methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
try {
  input = myInput.nextInt();
} catch (InputMismatchException e) {
  System.out.println("Please enter a proper value");
}
```

One possible approach is to use a loop and check for the input you expect say an `int` between 1 and 3,

```
int input = 0;
while(input < 1 || input > 3) {
  if (myInput.hasNextInt()) {
    input = myInput.nextInt();
  } else if (myInput.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println("Please enter a proper value");
    myInput.next();
  } else {
    System.err.println("No more input");
    System.exit(1);
  }
}
// input is 1,2 or 3. Or the program ended.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a while loop.

```
// While the user keeps entering valid input
while(input >= 1 && <= 3)
{
    System.out.println("Press 1 to calc circle, 2 for rect, 3 for cyln");

    try{

        input = myInput.nextInt();
    }

    catch(InputMismatchException e){

        System.out.println("Please enter a proper value");
    }

    if(input == 1)
    {
        System.out.println("enter radius");
        circle = myInput.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("area of circle is " +
        areas.area(circle));

    }

    else if(input == 2)
    {

        System.out.println("enter length and height");
        rect1 = myInput.nextDouble();
        rect2 = myInput.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("area of rect is " + areas.area(rect1,rect2));

    }

    else if(input == 3)
    {
        System.out.println("enter rad, height");
        cyl1 = myInput.nextDouble();
        cyl2 = myInput.nextDouble();

        // int useless = 0;
        // No need to make an integer for it. Just put a 0 there.

        System.out.println("Area of cyl is " + areas.area(cyl1, cyl2, 0));

    }
} // End of while loop
```

I would also like to consider using switch-case if you've learned that. Very useful here (much faster and easier to follow)

```
// Keep looping forever. If you want it to just keep running when the values are 1, 2, or 3 use:
// while(input >=1 && input <=3) instead of while(true)
while(true)
{
    System.out.println("Press 1 to calc circle, 2 for rect, 3 for cyln");

    try{

        input = myInput.nextInt();
    }

    catch(InputMismatchException e){

        System.out.println("Please enter a proper value");
    }

    switch(input) {
        case 1:
            // When it's 1
            System.out.println("enter radius");
            circle = myInput.nextDouble();

            System.out.println("area of circle is " + areas.area(circle));
            break; // Let's the switch know to stop running code and get out

        case 2:
            // When it's 2
            System.out.println("enter length and height");
            rect1 = myInput.nextDouble();
            rect2 = myInput.nextDouble();

            System.out.println("area of rect is " + areas.area(rect1,rect2));
            break;
        case 3:
            // When it's 3
            System.out.println("enter rad, height");
            cyl1 = myInput.nextDouble();
            cyl2 = myInput.nextDouble();

            // int useless = 0;
            // No need to make an integer for it. Just put a 0 there.

            System.out.println("Area of cyl is " + areas.area(cyl1, cyl2, 0));
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("You entered an invalid option. Try again");
    }

} // End of while loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Just looking through your code I realized that you might also want to put a similar try-catch structure when you ask for more inputs (inside the stacked if statements). So what I would suggest is creating a method to take input and check to make sure it is valid. For example:

```
public intInp(Scanner s)
{
    boolean v = false;
    int res = 0;
    do
    {
        try
        {
            res = s.nextInt();
            v = true;
        }
        catch(IOException | NumberFormatException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Oops, try again and enter a number please");
        }
    }while(v == false);
    return res;
}
```

and this for doubles:

```
public double doubleInp(Scanner s)
{
    boolean v = false;
    double res = 0.0
    do
    {
        try
        {
            res = s.nextDouble();
            v = true;
        }
        catch(IOException | NumberFormatException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Oops, try again and enter a number please");
        }
    }while(v == false);
    return res; 
}
```

Then just call the methods in order to save some code.